# call php file from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi I have searched the web but can't get this to work. I'm trying to call the file **databaseUpdated.php** (placed in the same folder as the **index.php** file) from a function that is called every 10 seconds.

If I place the following in the index.php

```
<script type='text/javascript'>updateboolean();</script>;
```

the function is runned so thats not the problem, the problem is that the php file is not read.

the file **databaseUpdated.php**

```
<body>
<?php

echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>updateboolean();</script>;");

?>
</body>
```

And here is my functions in the javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
        $.get("databaseUpdated.php");//Can't get this to work any obvious reason for this (And yes I have jquery working)?
        return false;            
    }, 10000);
    });



    function updateboolean(){
        alert("Database updated");
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
```

Thanks in advance =)

Edit

**_________________________________________________________________________________________**

When I do

alert(data); in the below function I get the result as the image will show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
               $.get('databaseUpdated.php', function(data) {
               alert('Load was performed.');
               alert(data);
               eval(data);
            });
        }, 5000);
   });
```

[image]

But the "**eval(data)**"
doesn't seem to work

Comment: What error did you get in the console? Is there a HTTP request? What is the status code?

Comment: So, you have to load this php file every 10 seconds that, in your mind, should call a Javascript function? Why don't you just call the function every 10 seconds instead?

Comment: Define "Can't get this to work" - start by verifying  that a request is made to that url using your browser (e.g. chrome network tab) - and that the response (which you're ignoring - that's "ok") is not a http error.

Comment: I got it, i shoudn't have the html tags etc, now it works, thanks cfor the help =)

Comment: there is so much wrong loading a php file which writes a string which you [eval](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eval+is+evil) which calls a js function - instead of e.g. returning json and `if (data.success) { callthisFunction(); }` or at the very least using [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) - since that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get("databaseUpdated.php"); // This will only return contents of that file The scripts in that file are not executed. To execute them you need to do eval(). So Try This

$.get('databaseUpdated.php', function(data) {
       eval(data);
    });
```

Also, may be you will require to change your php file as following:

```
echo ("updateboolean();");
```

Answer (score 3):

where is your callback function for ajax 
this is how it should be

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
               $.get('databaseUpdated.php', function(data) {
               alert('Load was performed.');
            });
        }, 10000);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function() {
           $.get('databaseUpdated.php', function(data) {
           alert("Database updated");
           // or alert(data); //in case you return data from php
           document.location.reload(true);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

By doing `$.get("databaseUpdated.php")`, you request the PHP page, but ignore the return results.

Try this:

PHP

```
echo "updateboolean();";
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getScript("databaseUpdated.php");
```

Answer (score -3):

try this in place of your echo

```
 echo "<script>updateboolean();</script>";
```